# AngularJS: Controller inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route, angular1.6

I have problem with controller load when I triggered ng-route. 
This is my main page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head ng-app="testapp">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
            <title>XX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav ng-controller="defaultnav"></nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my app.js file:

```
 var app = angular.module('testapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when("/", {
                    templateUrl: "index.html"
                })
                .when("/page1", {
                    templateUrl: "page1.html"
                })
        })
```

inside the page1.html I inisiate controller like this:

```
<div ng-controller="page1">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    app.controller('page1', function ($scope) {
        // code...
    })
</script>
```

I don't know best practice to handle this. When I code this I got error with [Error, ctrlreg] it says that I have problem about registering controller.
Please give me advice to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After an angular app is bootstrapped you can not register controllers with. Tou need to do that before app bootstraps.

Comment: ng-app="testapp" and module name is "enterprise" ?

Comment: In addition to what Manish said: the controller should be specified in the route definition, not using ng-controller in the view.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I edited this.

Comment: what if I add `.when("/page1", {
                    templateUrl: "page1.html", controller: "page1"
                })` ? it's not working too

Answer (score 1):

1. In JS, the app name in line `var app = angular.module('enterprise', ['ngRoute']);` is `enterprise`
2. In HTML, `<head ng-app="testapp">`, the app name is `testapp`. Change to `<head ng-app="enterprise">`
3. Its best practice to load the java script seperately. so remove js code from html and keep it in seperate file and load it

[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oDFG8nTWVfvZj3cz33c6?p=preview) for working demo in plnkr.

You can use AngularJS ngRoute:

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
  })

  // route for the contact page
  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactController'
  })

  //otherwise redirect to home
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/home"
  });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!!!!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Contact us!.';
});
```